# Windows updateを取得し再起動するバッチ

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Windows updateを自動で取得して再起動までするバッチを教えていただきたいです。

Windows updateの自動設定の機能が使えないため、ログオンスクリプトかスタートアップに設定したいと考えております。

更新プログラムは、インターネットに取りに行きます。
ご教示お願い致します。

Comment: これらの記事にヒントがありそうです。[Windowsの更新プログラムをMicrosoft Updateカタログからダウンロードして手動インストールする方法](https://paso-kake.com/it/windows10/3443/), [Windows Update カタログからドライバーや修正プログラムを含む更新プログラムをダウンロードする方法](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/323166/), [Microsoft Update カタログから累積更新プログラムをダウンロードするVBScript](https://www.ka-net.org/blog/?p=11757)

Comment: あるいは、こちらの記事の方が近いのかも。[【Windows 10】Windows Update の基礎知識、現在のバージョンを確認する方法](https://laboradian.com/windows10-windows-update/), [PowerShell で Windows Update を実行する](https://qiita.com/asterisk9101/items/8a52562ade6d2a47a467), [Windows 10 更新プログラムのチェックがグレーアウトされて押せないときの対処法 (コマンドでWindows Updateの更新チェックを実行する)](https://mseeeen.msen.jp/how-to-windows-update-when-check-button-is-disabled/), [面倒な“Windows 10の更新”をスクリプト化できる新たな選択肢（その1）](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1808/06/news012.html), [面倒な“Windows 10の更新”をスクリプト化できる新たな選択肢（その2）](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1808/22/news011.html)